# 2 PPPOE on different computer

Tags: networking, router, adsl, dsl, pppoe

I have an ISP which provides "WAN Miniport (PPPOE)" connection type. It means they gave me the username and password so that I can log into in. They have registered my MAC address on their website. I can add 3 MAC address so other computers at home can also log into in using username password. Now the question is, Once I'm log into my PC using username and password, I cannot login into another PC. If I log out from my PC I will able to login into other PC. Is there any trick or way to bypass it ? I mean if I try to login into another pc then My connection will be closed and his/her connection will be started.

My connection type description :

[image]

Is there any way to make 2 simultaneously connected using username and password?

Comment: By "my MAC address", which one do you mean?  You might have provided the MAC address of your PC or the MAC address of your router.  It makes a difference when it comes to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most ADSL modems come with basic router functions, including NAT. Therefore you should be able to configure the PPPoE connection on the ADSL modem itself – its built-in router will use NAT to allow multiple computers to share the same connection. (Look for some settings like "bridge mode" vs "router mode" (currently it's bridged), or just "PPPoE".)

If your modem cannot do that, buy a router which can & connect it to the modem – again, many home "wireless routers" support PPPoE for their WAN connection. *(Double-NAT will not be an issue here.)*

(Windows itself also has "Internet connection sharing", but it needs a PC that's always on, with a wired Ethernet connection, and ideally with *two* Ethernet connections – one to the modem, one to other computers.)

Comment: As far as I know what you said is not the point. See , ISP gave me the username and password and registered the my router's MAC. So when I'm logged into the ISP using PPPOE my friend on other hand cannot connect to my username and password.(I have also registered his MAC) So once I disconnect my connection, He is able to login into it and he can use my internet due to same ISP. Now until and unless he won't logout I wont be able to login into my ISP. Is there any way so that we can share username password since we are not on same network but on same ISP and we can login into in at same time ?

Comment: P.S : I have no access to the modem. They have plugged cable into the router.

Comment: So your computers are not on the same LAN, but at different places entirely? Why didn't you mention that before? But regardless, what I said still applies here.

Comment: Can I do it if I don't use router ? Instead of router what if I plug cable to my laptop and login in.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand from your comments, you are asking whether you and your friend can connect to the internet using the same ISP account from different locations.

If that's the case, then the answer is likely to be no. The ISP will typically require multiple accounts for multiple connections.